# Partial ConstraintSet Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create and animation using ConstraintSet from layout files:

```
final ConstraintSet target = new ConstraintSet();
target.clone(context, R.layout.layout_name);
TransitionManager.beginDelatedTransition(sceneRoot);
target.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

This works to do the animation, but I want to bind the animation to a drawer view, so it happens as the user manually drags the drawer. In the drawer listener, I can get a `slideOffset` float that gets called when the drawer is dragged, but I cannot find a way to calculate a step in the ConstraintSet animation process to use. How can I get this, or is there a better, existing method to bind the animation to a listener like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I feared, it appears that, currently, this isn't really possible with ConstraintSet. The good news is that ConstraintLayout `2.0` is coming soon, and includes an out-of-the-box solution for this issue: [MotionLayout](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d). MotionLayout will allow for all sorts of complicated animations with ConstraintLayout UIs, and has a `setProgress()` method that can be bound directly to a drawer listener (or any other linear animation step provider).